# How to make group button?

Tags: android, button

I have 3 buttons. And the problem is I can't put 3 buttons in centre of layout. 
The problem will show when I make my phone horizontal, the buttons will show at left of layout not at center.

Comment: Could you provide an example? (screenshot?)

Comment: Set the gravity of your layout to center horizontal?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to embed a relative layout inside the linear layout.  Similar to what is shown below.  This should allow you to get the buttons in a group that can be manipulated better that if a LinearLayout is maintained. One other thing do you have a separate layout for the landscape orientation?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: doenst have to be a relative layout, you can do the same using a linear layout in horizontal orientation.

Comment: I guess that would depend on how the buttons are arranged.  If you want multiple buttons on the same line then as far as I know you would need a relative layout.  If you are just looking to center stacked buttons then yes gravity setting should be all that is needed.

Comment: as i said you can make a cenetered horizontal line of buttons with a linear layout as well. Never use RelativeLayouts align Features if you dont have to, because linear is much faster.

Comment: Still new to android, but I see what you are saying now.  I also did not know that using a linear layout was faster and I will have to remember that in future development.

Comment: it isnt faster by default but if you are using features like align bottom of another element, the layout has to layout itself, till the element has been drawn and then redraw again to align the 2nd element below it. thats what makes the relative layout slower